# Using aTan2 to face an object to its destination

Tags: c++, math, matrix, rotation, atan2

I've created an object that moves towards its destination with inertia. I am having alot of trouble getting the object to face its destination. My code is simple, it calculates the angle, converts it to degrees and passes that angle to the Matrix4 Rotate function, which adjusts the localTransform (scenegraph).

The problem is that the object spawns, and then just rotates endlessly. It slowly progresses towards its target, but just keeps spinning. I've tested it without translation, it spins regardless on the spot. All I need is for the object to face its destination. My Translate/Rotate functions work correctly, I've used it to rotate an object, have an object spawn with its parent's rotation and head in that direction. They provide 1:1 results with the GLM library.

I've tried swapping the order in aTan2, removing the degrees conversion, (though that does nothing, the Rotate function takes degrees) and swapping translation/rotation order.

localTransform is the combined rotation/scale/translation matrix. row[3]column[1] is Y. [3][0] is X.

```
float fAngle = atan2(v3Destination[1] - localTransform.data[3][1] , v3Destination[0] - localTransform.data[3][0]);
float fAngleDegrees = fAngle * 180 / PI;
localTransform = Matrix4::Rotate(localTransform, fAngleDegrees, Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

Vector3 Movement;
Movement[0] = v3Destination[0] - localTransform.data[3][0];
Movement[1] = v3Destination[1] - localTransform.data[3][1];

Movement = Movement * fSpeed * Application.GetTimeStep();
localTransform = Matrix4::Translate(localTransform, Movement);
```

Any advice on how to handle this? This is all in 2D coordinates, however the rotation is done on the Z-Axis.

Comment: It seems that you are calculating the angle of the vector from the object to the target, but don't take the facing of the object into account. After the object has been turned in one time step, you turn it by the angle of the vector again in the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch, but is the localTransform matrix completely recomputed each time step?

Or could you be adding a rotation to a matrix that's already been rotated in the previous iteration.

This could explain the continuous rotation.

Comment: The localTransform is persistent between loops. It's the current X/Y/Z/Rotation/Scale.

Oh, I get it, the fAngle is computed every loop without regard for the previous fAngle, so its just reapplying the same rotation over and over. How do I keep adjusting the angle towards the point (in case it moves down the X/Y and not in a straight line) without just readding the angle?

Comment: I'd probably recompute the whole matrix, starting from an identity matrix. Then rotating by the angle, and translating into the current position.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I erased 00, 01, 10, and 11 (the rotation data) every loop for the objects I need to calculate the angle for. Thankyou :) The endless looping is over.